# scipy.optimize.minimize: success is True, but L-BFGS-B prints a worrying warning

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I use `scipy.optimize.minimize()` for univariate linear regression where I want the cost function to be different that quadratic (thus can't use `scipy.stats.linregress()`).
Because I specify bounds (`a` and `b` need to be positive in my `y = a*x + b`), SciPy chooses `L-BFGS-B` as a solver. I trust SciPy on that, plus I don't change any of its default parameter values.

The result of fitting is:

```
 Warning:  more than 10 function and gradient                                                            
   evaluations in the last line search.  Termination                                                     
   may possibly be caused by a bad search direction.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>                                                                                                                                                            
      jac: array([4.42014425e+00, 1.81898925e-04])                                                                                                                                                                 
  message: 'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'                                                                                                                                                       
     nfev: 105                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      nit: 7                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     njev: 35                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   status: 0                                                                                             
  success: True
```

So, on one hand, success is `True` (great), but then the Warning message suggests that perhaps the algorithm terminated in a bad spot because of some other stop condition. The question is then: what shall I do with it? I can't even detect this situation automatically, as it is just a Warning printed on the screen. Although the `d` dict mentioned [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) could be helpful, it is not returned by the [wrapping function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult).

In short: Is it enough to check the 'success' flag? Should I fight it with parameters manipulation or is that fine?

Comment: Who knows what you are doing. Compared to some optimized symbolic gradient-evaluation you seem to hope for numeric-differentiation which will always be less stable/robust. Only you know if you can provide the gradient directly (or at least non-numerically using jax or something similar).

Comment: @sascha, true, I don't know what I am doing, as I fit independently tons of experimental datasets, sometimes perhaps full of noise / outliers, scattered, etc. Hence purely numerical approach. But in any case I'd expect the algorithm to clearly communicate what it did and to what extent the result can be trusted. And that is what I ask in my question, I am not asking for magic that would fix the world, thus I don't understand how could your comment be helpful.